# How to add PDF metadata when printing an HTML page with a browser?

Tags: html, pdf, metadata, opera

I'm using HTML to generate some documents as I'm mastering the layouting much more than Latex or Word.

I'm generating my HTML page and convert it to PDF by printing the page with Opera.

Everything works well, the margins and so on.

I was just wondering if it was also possible to add the PDF metadata (author, keywords...) directly in the HTML page so that when printing, they would also be in the PDF document. Something like:

```
<meta name="PDFauthor" content="coucou">
```